# Template demands Type and compiles anyway

Tags: c++, templates, types, compiler-errors

I have been searching on stack overflow, in my textbook, and google and everywhere, for like 2 days now for to try and fix/understand this issue.
I am writing this code out of a book I bought and it looks right to me, and I have gotten the code to compile after misspelling 'appnd' and 'prepnd' on purpose, and using GNU compiler 10.2.1, but wanted to know why basically and see if I could make it also run on clang++ and not have the spelling error and all that.

Like I said, this code compiles on my computer with GNU, but also on compiler explorer it says there is an issue with the same compiler(the same issue).

So this error keeps coming up saying I cant make an append or prepend with no type when dude(Dmytro Kedyk) is using a template as the type.

And I know there is an std::append or whatever for strings, but i am not using std, so like what gives.

And if you look at the code he uses append before the line throwing the error, but it has no issue with append there.

I seems like it should work, and if I misspell 'append or prepend' it works on GNU. why is clang not playing nice, or am I not playing nice with clang?

```
 error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘append’ with no type [-fpermissive]
```

On this line

```
 template<typename ARGUMENT> append(ARGUMENT const& a){
```

On the second line with the append I keep getting an error

Notes: This is not my code! This is just from a book I own.

```
transcribed with small changes and added notes from:
    page 44 "Implementing Useful Algorithms in C++", by: Dmytro Kedyk
```

```
template <typename ITEM> class simpleDoublyLinkedList{          //template for item and class dec
    struct Node{
        ITEM item;                                              //data
        Node *next, *prev;                                      //links to next and last
        template<typename ARGUMENT>                             //tempalting for argument
        Node(ARGUMENT const& a): item(a), next(0), prev(0) {}   //creating node obj inside Node struct
    } *root, *last;                                             //pointers to next and last
    void cut(Node* n){                                          //funct to unlink node, takes node *
        assert(n);                                              //assert on node object
        (n == last ? last : n->next->prev) = n->prev;           // 
        (n == root ? root : n->prev->next) = n->next;           //
    }
public:
    simpleDoublyLinkedList(): root(0), last(0) {}               //
    template<typename ARGUMENT> append(ARGUMENT const& a){      //line throwing error
        Node* n = new Node(a);                                  //making new node 'with new'
        n->prev = last;                                         //add to end of list
        if(last){last->next;}                                   //move down list 
        last =n;                                                //
        if(root){root = n;}                                     //if root is true make root n
    }   
    class Iterator{ 
        Node* current;                                          //current node obj (like 'this' but not predefined)
    public:
        Iterator(Node* n): current(n){}                         // member taking node
        typedef Node* Handle;                                   //Handle pointer type made of node type
        Handle getHandle(){return current;}                     //function to return current as handle 
        Iterator&  operator++(){                                //overloading ++ operator
            assert(current);
            current = current->next;
            return* this;
        };
        Iterator& operator--(){                                 //overloading -- operator
            assert(current);
            assert(current);
            current = current->prev;
            return* this;
        };
        ITEM& operator* ()const{assert(current);return current->item;} //overloading *
        ITEM& operator->()const{assert(current); return &current->item;} //overloading ->
        bool operator==(Iterator const& rhs)const{return current == rhs.current;} //overloading ==
    };
    Iterator begin(){return Iterator(root);}                    //returing root from iterator
    Iterator  rBegin(){return Iterator(last);}
    Iterator end(){return Iterator(0);}
    Iterator rEnd(){return Iterator(0);}
    void moveBefore(Iterator what, Iterator where){             //function to move items in list
        assert(what != end());                                  //assert what is not end 
        if(what != where){                                      //omit self refrence
            Node *n = what.getHandle(), *w = where.getHandle(); //
            cut(n);
            n->next = w;
            if(w){
                n->prev = w->prev;
                w->prev = n;
            }else{
                n->prev = last;
                last =n;
            }
            if(n->prev){n->prev->next = n;}
            if(w == root){root= n;}
        }
    }
    template<typename ARGUMENT> prepend(ARGUMENT const& a){      //other line throwing error
        append(a);
        moveBefore(rBegin(), begin());
    }
    void remove(Iterator what){
        assert(what != end());
        cut(what.getHandle());
        delete what.getHandle();
    }
    simpleDoublyLinkedList (simpleDoublyLinkedList const& rhs){
        for (Node* n = rhs.root; n; n=n->next){append(n->item);}}
    simpleDoublyLinkedList &operator=(simpleDoublyLinkedList const&rhs){
        return genericAssign(*this, rhs);}
    ~simpleDoublyLinkedList(){
        while(root){
            Node* toBeDeleted = root;
            root = root->next;
            delete toBeDeleted;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

append and prepend are functions but he has not put a return type in front of them. I think those lines should have a void return type, like this

```
template<typename ARGUMENT> void append(ARGUMENT const& a){      //line throwing error

template<typename ARGUMENT> void prepend(ARGUMENT const& a){      //other line throwing error
```

Because they have no return type, the compiler is attempting to interpret the function name as the return type.  It has not seen that type before (because it's not a type) so it complains that the "type" is undefined.    (Well technically, if it actually does build, I guess it assumes a void return type and lets you get away with it but warns you)